# What does it refer to in the passage?

Tags: pronouns

What does ***it*** refer to in the passage? Does it refer to U.S. electoral college?

> States that are teetering between parties are called "swing states."
>   In the past four election cycles, Ohio and Florida have been swing
>   states, twice providing electoral votes for a Democratic candidate,
>   and twice providing electoral votes for a Republican candidate. Think
>   about ***it***. Do you live in a safe state? If so, is it a Democratic or
>   Republican safe state? Do you live in a swing state? Are your
>   neighboring states swing or safe? Is the population in your state
>   increasing or decreasing? And do not forget, when you are watching the
>   electoral returns on election night every four years and the big map
>   of the United States is on the screen, know that the magic number is
>   270 and start adding.

https://ed.ted.com/lessons/does-your-vote-count-the-electoral-college-explained-christina-greer

Comment: It goes deeper than that

Answer (score 2):

This *it* is a sort of 'generic' or 'universal' pronoun referring to the entire context of the current discussion: "Think about everything we've just said."

And the entire sentence is a 'discourse marker' used to shift the discussion into a fresh context (or, possibly, to revert to an earlier context): "Apply what we've just said to *your* situation on election night."